# Relationship problem with 3 tables (Users, Roles & Permissions)

Tags: sql-server, database

I am developing a web application for my school.

The fields of my Users table are
-Username
-Hashed_password
-Salt
-Role_ID

There are 6 roles in my Roles table
-Main Administrator
-Tech Administrator
-Faculty Administrator
-Career Administrator
-Student
-Graduated

My problem is, how can I manage that when a user with Faculty Administrator Role can see all the students and graduateds that are related to its faculty? (Faculty is another table)

And also, how can I manage that when a user with Career Administrator Role can see all the students and graduateds that are related to its career? (Career is other table)

Do I need to create another tables to give permissions to that faculty or career or how do I relation the faculty or career depending on the type of user?

Comment: And what have you done so far???  Since you're still learning, this is good to attempt to do something.

Answer (score 0):

In the user table you need to add ID_Career and ID_faculty, with this all the users have their career and their faculty, so if a user with Faculty Administrator Role wants to see all the students from his faculty or career you only need to take the correspondant ID and make the search for all the students that have the same ID_Faculty or ID_Career.